# Email subject shortened in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have sent an email from CodeIgniter but I don't know why my email get's truncated or it gets included with black diamonds with a question mark in them. It is true I use Persian character but the header is utf-8 anyway. Here is the CodeIgniter Code to send email:

Just pay attention to the non-latin characters in the subject:

```
$configs = array(
                'protocol'=>'smtp',
                'wrapchars'=>150,
                'smtp_host'=>'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                'smtp_user'=>'cgmaster.iran@gmail.com',
                'smtp_pass'=>"09357758934",
                'smtp_port'=>'465',
                'mailtype'=>'html'      
                );
                $this->load->library("email", $configs);
                $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

                $this->email->to("mostafatalebi@rocketmail.com");
                $this->email->from("cgmaster.iran@gmail.com", wraptitle("", true, "email_from"));
                $this->email->subject("رمز عبو::نیازر");
                $this->email->message("Let's user CodeIgniter since it is really powerful.");

                $this->email->send();
```

Comment: What does wraptitle do? Is is multibyte safe?

Comment: I have edited it, and have placed it without wraptitle function

Comment: Is it possible that your mailclient/webservice overrides your UTF8? What if you add those chars to the body of the mail?

Comment: no utf-8 supports persian characters

Comment: now it is done, I had to put the charset right in the config array. I thought it is OK since codeIgniter documentation has declared that not defining the charset in the config means the same as utf-8

Comment: @Mostafa This has something to do with charset. Kindly see your codeigniter config file.

Comment: @Mostafa => Fast Learner ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`utf-8` supports Persian characters. But I had the same problem before, you have to explicitly state the `charset` to utf-8 in `$config array`.