# CodeIgniter : how to send HTML e-mails with non-latin characters

Tags: php, codeigniter, utf-8

I am developing an open source leave management system for NGOs. The software must be available in many languages; for example french and khmer.

I'm struggling while trying to send HTML e-mails with *CodeIgniter 2.2.0*. I know this is possible and that this question has been already asked here. But I am still failing.

What I am trying to achieve:

- Parse a view to create the HTML body of the e-mail.
- Send the e-mail in HTML format.

This is working for english content but it doesn't work when the e-mail contains non-latin characters.

I followed the advices of the previous answers :

- All the files of my project are UTF-8 (no BOM) encoded.
- Some people suggest to set 'newline' and 'crlf' settings to "\r\n".

Let's take an example with my project :

- The [CI View](https://github.com/bbalet/lms/blob/master/application/views/emails/fr/request.php) that contains the HTML body of the e-mail (example in french) :
- The [CI controller](https://github.com/bbalet/lms/blob/master/application/controllers/leaves.php#L235) that sends the e-mail :
- The config I use (I tried with various SMTP servers; the demo demo.leave-management-system.org is connected to GMail):

---

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['useragent'] = 'CodeIgniter';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'localhost';
$config['smtp_user'] = '';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '';
$config['_smtp_auth'] = TRUE;
$config['smtp_port'] = '25';
$config['smtp_timeout'] = '20';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';   //'iso-8859-1'
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['wordwrap'] = FALSE;
//$config['wrapchars'] = 80;
$config['validate'] = FALSE;
$config['priority'] = 3;
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655632/email-subject-shortened-in-codeigniter , hope this helps,

Comment: I already read this answer. The solution given is to set 'charset' to 'utf-8' in the config array. I've done that but it didn't solve the problem. Plus this question is related to the subject and my problem is related to the massage. Thank you anyway.

Comment: i see , Did you see this http://www.ustrem.org/en/articles/send-mail-using-phpmailer-en/ ?

Comment: The article is related to PHPMailer. Although they are similar, I use the e-mail class of CodeIgniter and not this library. I've read it carefully, but nothing new (the charset is set to 'utf-8' as mentionned into the article).

Comment: I agree again but the core is same for CI email library and php mailer. You can check email.pho file in system->library folder

Comment: The core of the mail lib differs with PHPMailer. I'll switch to PHP Mailer that I was able to make it works with khmer by forcing the encoding of the body to quoted-printable. Unfortunately I am unable to do the same with CI mail lib...

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of search I've given up and decided to use PHPMailer with a wrapper for CodeIgniter. I don't know what is wrong, but the only way to make it work is to explicitly set the **Encoding** property to *quoted-printable* as into this example with PHPMailer :

```
<?php
echo "Start<br />\n";
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->setFrom('test@gmail.com', 'ប្រភេទនៃការសុំច្បាប់');
$mail->addAddress('target@example.com');
$mail->WordWrap = 70;
$mail->CharSet  = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Encoding = 'quoted-printable';
$mail->XMailer  = 'Test';
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$message = '<html><head><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta charset="UTF-8"></head><body>test: <ul><li>ប្រភេទឈប់សម្រាកបានធ្វើអោយទាន់សម័យដោយជោគជ័យ</li></ul></body></html>';
$mail->Subject = 'Khmer - ប្រភេទនៃការសុំច្បាប់';
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->send();
```

If you don't set the **Encoding** property, the Subject and Sender will be correctly set but not the HTML Body...

The problem of CI Mail library is that you must escape all non-latin characters of the Body. It is unrealistic if you work with an HTML view containing non-european language.

You could use this [wrapper for CodeIgniter](https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-phpmailer) but don't forget to explicitly set **Encoding** property to *quoted-printable* before updating the Body property.